# How can I write a "subcaption" on top of figure using subfigure package. But only in selected subfigure

Tags: subcaption

I'm trying to change bubcaption to the top but can't find a way using subfigure package. Can not add captio/ subcaption package because they crash with subfigure package, and I'm already half way through a very long document. That's what I type:

```
    \begin{figure}[h]
        \centering
        \subfigure{A}
        \includegraphics[scale=0.35]{kinase/grapmorpfirstadd}
        \label{subfigure:kinmorfirst}
        \hspace{1mm}
        \subfigure{B}
        \includegraphics[scale=0.35]{kinase/grapdamgofirstadd}
        \label{subfigure:kindamgofirst}

        \caption[Concentration response curve in the presence of 1$\mu$M PMA]{Concentration response curve in the presence of 1$\mu$M PMA (A) Morphine treatment  (B) DAMGO treatment}  
        \label{figure:kinfirstadd}
        \end{figure}
```

The A or B is in the bottom left, I want them on top left.
[image]
Thanks

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us to help you and complete your code to create a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`. Since you are explicitly dependent on particular packages, posting code without those is hardly going to make it easier for people to help you.

Comment: But do note that if you are using [this](http://ctan.org/pkg/subfigure) it is considered obsolete....

Comment: \documentclass[phd,titlesmallcaps, examinerscopy, copyrightpage]{mqthesis}

Comment: It's a very long document with many parts to it.\\ It does finish with \end{document}

Comment: Please read the link I posted which explains how to construct an MWE. If my answer below does not solve the problem, we cannot do much if we do not have a compilable document we can use to reproduce. I don't have `mqthesis.cls` and I can only guess what might be in it. Follow the instructions to create an example we can compile here so that we can help you.

Comment: Also, use the `edit` to complete the code in your question - don't post it in comments.

Answer (score 4):

***Do NOT use this code in new documents.*** `subfigure` is deprecated and ought not be used. Instead use `subfig` or `subcaption`.

You can use `adjustbox` to align things:

```
\usepackage{graphicx,subfigure,adjustbox}
\begin{document}
  \begin{figure}[h]
    \centering
    \mbox{}%
    \adjustbox{valign=T}{\subfigure{A}}
    \adjincludegraphics[valign=T,scale=0.35]{example-image-a}
    \label{subfigure:kinmorfirst}
    \hspace{1mm}
    \adjustbox{valign=T}{\subfigure{B}}
    \adjincludegraphics[valign=T,scale=0.35]{example-image-a}
    \label{subfigure:kindamgofirst}

    \caption[Concentration response curve in the presence of 1$\mu$M PMA]{Concentration response curve in the presence of 1$\mu$M PMA (A) Morphine treatment  (B) DAMGO treatment}
    \label{figure:kinfirstadd}
  \end{figure}
\end{document}
```

[image: aligned things]

Comment: The problem is once I remove the package subfigure and add subfig I get hundred errors. Is that common?

Comment: Yes, because the syntax to declare a sub figure is different.  I would use subcaption.

Comment: @MarinaJSantiago You don't need to remove `subfigure` to use my solution. I don't understand the problem.

Comment: @cfr You explicitly admonish visitors to *not* use the `subfigure` package, so that last comment doesn't make sense. Beyond that, it would also be good if you could actually supply a solution in line with the best-practices you recommend, i.e. using `subfig` instead of `subfigure`.

Comment: @E.P. It makes perfect sense. It is perfectly sensible to say: look, I wouldn't use package X but, if you must, solution Y will work with package X. The reason for providing this solution was that the OP was already a long way into a long document and using `subfigure`. Without rewriting a lot of existing code, no better option is available. That's why I started with the warning not to use this in ***new*** documents. But the OP's document was not new.

Comment: @cfr The point was that telling people off for following your advice is not on the awesome side of life. In any case, your answer is one of the top google hits for the equivalent `subfig` query, and it could perfectly well address that case too, but unfortunately it doesn't.

Comment: @E.P. I was not telling anybody off for anything. I simply stated the facts. And, as MaxNoe suggests, `subcaption` is really a better option than `subfig` for new documents. `subfig` is just easier to substitute for `subfigure` if updating old code. And there is already an answer here addressing the use of `subcaption` together with `floatrow`. There is no need for my answer to duplicate that effort.

Answer (score 2):

Here's one option using the powerful [`floatrow`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/floatrow) package in combo with [`subcaption`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/subcaption) ([`subfig`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/subfig) could have been an option too); since the labeling is dome automatically, you can easily cross-reference the subfigures:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{floatrow}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\renewcommand\thesubfigure{\Alph{subfigure}}

\begin{document}

Some references to Figure~\ref{fig:test} and its subfigures~\ref{sfig:testa} and~\ref{sfig:testb}.
\begin{figure}
\floatsetup[subfigure]{style=plain,heightadjust=object,
capbesideposition={left,top},capbesidesep=space}
\ffigbox[\FBwidth]
  {%
    \begin{subfloatrow}\useFCwidth
    \fcapside[\FBwidth]
      {\caption{}\label{sfig:testa}}
      {\includegraphics[width=4cm]{example-image-a}}
    \fcapside[\FBwidth]
      {\caption{}\label{sfig:testb}}
      {\includegraphics[width=4cm]{example-image-b}}
  \end{subfloatrow}%
  }
  {\caption{A figure with two subfigures}\label{fig:test}}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

[image]

I agree with **cfr**, you shouldn't use the obsolete `subfigure` package anymore.

Comment: I'm getting errors per figure I have in the whole document?!

Comment: @MarinaJSantiago Of course, you need to replace your `\subfigure` commands/environments for those of the suggested packages.